# Active node on Fanytree Init

Tags: javascript, flask, fancytree

I am trying to activate a node of the tree generated by the fancytree using Javascript. I am using flask as server side framework and passing the key as a server side variable. As mentioned on http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/index.html#sample-api.html, I am using the following script:

```
$("#tree2").fancytree("getTree").activateKey('{{key}}');
```

However, this does not activate any key in spite of the key being present.

P.S. I am customizing my key using alphanumeric code in the source ajax data for fancy tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok, given that the selector exists and `'{{key}}'` resolves to an existing key (you might want to check that using `console.log(...)`).

Note that the nodes are only available, *after* the ajax request has returned, so you only can lookup those nodes in the `tree.init` event or after this happened.

Comment: I was not using the init method. Thanks for telling me.